# Data binding issue on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a page that works fine when running from visual studio and installed on my machine.  However, once I install it on our server, the page will initially load fine but when the button is clicked, it just returns with a "URL was not found" error.

I have the issue tracked down to the data binding for the drop down list.  If I removed it, the page works fine on the server.

Any suggestions for what to look at on the server or in my code will be greatly appreciated.

My aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchLandmarks.aspx.cs" Inherits="TripRequestPortal.SearchLandmarks" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManagerSearchLandmarks" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerNumber" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxDateFrom" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblDateFrom" runat="server" Text="Date From: " />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" />
        <asp:Image ID="imageDateFrom" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar_icon.jpg" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarExtenderDateFrom" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDateFrom" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imageDateFrom" />
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtenderDateFrom" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDateFrom" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date"/>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidatorDateFrom" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtenderDateFrom" IsValidEmpty="true" InvalidValueMessage="Inputted date not valid." EmptyValueMessage="Check box is checked so a date is required." />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxOrigin" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblOrigin" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="listOrigins" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            DataTextField="LANDMARKNAME" DataValueField="PRIKEY"  />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
            onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringTripStatus %>" 
            FilterExpression="customer='{0}'" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringTripStatus.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT PRIKEY, CUSTOMER, CONCAT(CONCAT(LANDMARKNAME, ' | '), SITEID) AS LANDMARKNAME FROM LANDMARKS ORDER BY LANDMARKNAME">
            <FilterParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblCustomerNumber" DefaultValue="-1" 
                    Name="newparameter" PropertyName="Text" />
            </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

my code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TripRequestPortal
{
    public partial class SearchLandmarks : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCustomerNumber.Text = "5";
        }

        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("TripEntry.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the page on the server itself using `localhost` so you can see the error messages?  (or turn off remoteErrors in the configuration file).  Is `TripEntry.aspx` file getting published as well to the server?

Comment: Where is the page "TripEntry.aspx" located in your file structure? My guess is, the redirect is not finding that page and you will need Response.Redirect("~/TripRequestPortal/TripEntry.aspx"); OR Response.Redirect("~/TripEntry.aspx");  Let us know if that works

Answer (score 0):

> I have the issue tracked down to the data binding for the drop down
>   list. If I removed it, the page works fine on the server.

so there should not be a issue with `Response.Redirect("TripEntry.aspx");`

try

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    lblCustomerNumber.Text = "5";
}
```

Comment: The redirect is not a problem.  I have tried using !IsPostBack without any success.  The Page_Load is not getting called after the button click.

Comment: Dang it, the comment posted before I was ready.  One of our vendors has started looking at the issue.  He created a new site on the same server and installed the application under it.  That version works without a problem.  There is something different between the site I created and the site he created.

Answer (score 0):

Our vendor has found that is has to do with the host header.  He created his own site in IIS and installed the application to it and it worked fine.  He started testing the site that I had created and he found that when he removed host name it worked fine.  If he added the host name to the site he created, it stopped working.

We are looking into the firewall and DNS now.

To expand further...

It was a firewall issue.  The size limits were too small.  Once these were adjusted, it started working.